# Webpack is not bundling css from node_modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, webpack

I'm migrating a react website to webpack 4 (from 3) but have been running into some strange problems when using webpack for css.

It works fine for the css that I wrote myself, but any css from third party components in node_modules does not seem to be included at all.

Here is an example of my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const config = {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /global\.css$/],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [/node_modules/, /global\.css$/],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 0,
              modules: true,
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/jpg'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx'
    ],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    },
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),
    new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: require('html-webpack-template'),
        inject: false,
        appMountId: 'app',
      })
  ],
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.hot) {
    // Cannot use 'contenthash' when hot reloading is enabled.
    config.output.filename = '[name].[hash].js';
  }

  return config;
};
```

Only css from my own files are included in the generated bundle.

I'm using the latest versions:

```
"webpack": "^4.41.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
```

Greatful for any help!

[Layout of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRceV.png)

Comment: How are you importing the CSS from the packages?

Comment: I'm not specifically importing any css from the packages. In the previous project, all the css got extracted in one big bundle (using ExtractTextPlugin which is now deprecated). I had expected it to work the same now, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Ahhhhh... there was indeed one css import for bootstrap that I missed when migrating the project. Added it and now everything works! :)

Thanks for pointing it out!